# internationalizable through the use of a resource bundle in Findbugs

Tags: java, findbugs

There is an Error coming in Find Bugs as follows ,

Method  passes constant string to title/label of component

"This method creates a component and passes a string literal to the title or label of the component. As this string will be shown to users, it should be internationalizable through the use of a resource bundle."

The code i have used is :

```
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Select");
```

Why is this wrong and how can i fix it.

Comment: FindBugs is asking you to make this static text "Select" into a dynamic one which gets its value from a `ResourceBundle` that changes based on the language specific to the user. Something like *messages_en.properties has the text Select* whereas *messages_fr.properties has the text sélectionner* because you don't want to show English static texts to a French User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set values by using set components (properties) to the object than initializing values directly through the constructor.

Eg -

```
 JLabel mylbl = new JLabel("myName");
```

You should better to practice to use above syntax as follow

> **setText(String text)**
>   *Defines the single line of text this component will display.*

```
JLabel mylbl = new JLabel();
mylbl.setText("myName");
```

*For the More info, refer* [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java/Orz4ZySmp_o)